# Paste data to the first free row of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a script for copying and pasting data from one worksheet to another.

I mostly threw together bits of code from tutorials etc. so there are some lines of code I don't entirely know the purpose of.

The script worked in my test sheets but now I've implemented it into the real workbook. If the data to copy is in row 1079 it will also be in row 1079 in the other sheet.

```vb
Sub Übertragen()

lastrow = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lastrow
    Dim rgCopy As Range

    Set rgCopy = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2").Range("D" & r)
    Set rgPaste = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("G" & r)

    Set rgCopy2 = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2").Range("E" & r)
    Set rgPaste2 = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("I" & r)

    Set rgCopy3 = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2").Range("F" & r)
    Set rgPaste3 = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("L" & r)

    Set rgCopy4 = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2").Range("H" & r)
    Set rgPaste4 = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("J" & r)

    With Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2")
        If .Range("I" & r).Value Like "eingegangen*" And .Cells(r, "S") <> 1 Then
            .Cells(r, "S") = 1
            rgCopy.Copy
            rgPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            rgCopy2.Copy
            rgPaste2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            rgCopy3.Copy
            rgPaste3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            rgCopy4.Copy
            rgPaste4.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Cells(r, "B") = Date
            Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Cells(r, "C") = "status"
            Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Cells(r, "E") = "company name"
            lastRowRpt = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            'Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2").Range("A" & lastRowRpt + 1).Select
        End If
    End With
Next r
End Sub
```

The last line of code is a comment because it stopped working but I didn't want to delete it. There's probably some other things that aren't great in my code but other than the issue I'm asking about it does what it should.

I assume the reason this is happening is related to the entire **r** and **lastrow** thing.

Comment: Say what you want not what you do not want.

Comment: QuIcker to use e.g. `rgPaste.value=rgcopy.value` and dispense with copy/paste. Personally I wouldn't even bother with all those variables. You could use `With` to tidy up the code.

Comment: its supposed to get pasted into first free row of the other worksheet @niton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to sum data into another open workbook starting from the row 2. Below is the code for this task. Please make sure to change the name of the report workbook as needed by modifying the line where rptSht is defined:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Übertragen()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowRpt As Long, r As Long
    Dim rgDCopy As Range, rgECopy As Range, rgFCopy As Range, rgHCopy As Range
    Dim dataSht As Worksheet, rptSht As Worksheet

    ' Define your data and report worksheets
    Set dataSht = Workbooks("A1.xlsm").Worksheets("A2")
    Set rptSht = Workbooks("B1.xlsm").Worksheets("B2")

    ' Find the last row in the data worksheet
    lastRow = dataSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through rows in the data worksheet
    For r = 2 To lastRow

        ' Define ranges for data in columns D, E, F, and H
        Set rgDCopy = dataSht.Range("D" & r)
        Set rgECopy = dataSht.Range("E" & r)
        Set rgFCopy = dataSht.Range("F" & r)
        Set rgHCopy = dataSht.Range("H" & r)

        With dataSht
            ' Check if the value in column I matches "eingegangen*" and column S is not equal to 1
            If .Range("I" & r).Value Like "eingegangen*" And .Cells(r, "S") <> 1 Then
                ' Find the last row in the report worksheet
                lastRowRpt = rptSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                With rptSht
                    ' Copy data from data worksheet to report worksheet
                    .Range("G" & lastRowRpt) = rgDCopy
                    .Range("I" & lastRowRpt) = rgECopy
                    .Range("L" & lastRowRpt) = rgFCopy
                    .Range("J" & lastRowRpt) = rgHCopy
                    .Range("B" & lastRowRpt) = Date
                    .Range("C" & lastRowRpt) = "status"
                    .Range("E" & lastRowRpt) = "company name"
                End With

                ' Update column S in the data worksheet
                .Cells(r, "S") = 1
            End If
        End With
    Next r

    ' Activate the report worksheet and select a cell below the last filled row
    rptSht.Activate
    rptSht.Range("A" & lastRowRpt + 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the copied rows to be in one continuous range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Übertragen()

    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, rB As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wsB = Workbooks("B1").Worksheets("B2")
    With wsB
        rB = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Set wsA = Workbooks("A1").Worksheets("A2")
    With wsA
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            If .Cells(r, "I") Like "einegangen*" And .Cells(r, "S") <> 1 Then
                 ' copy from row r to row rB
                 rB = rB + 1
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "G") = .Cells(r, "D")
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "I") = .Cells(r, "E")
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "L") = .Cells(r, "F")
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "J") = .Cells(r, "H")
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "B") = Date
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "C") = "status"
                 wsB.Cells(rB, "E") = "company name"
                 n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows scanned on " & wsA.Name & vbLf & _
           n & " rows copied to " & wsB.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```